# Freemarker giving unresolved reference for "TheApp" object

Tags: kotlin, freemarker

I'm following this [guide](https://ktor.io/servers/features/templates/freemarker.html) but "TheApp" portion is highlighted red and I get a blank webpage as output. Do I need to import some library for this to get recognized?

Also if I'm not passing any data into the template can I leave the 'model' as a blank string?

My kotlin code:

```
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.response.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import freemarker.cache.*
import io.ktor.freemarker.*
import io.ktor.freemarker.FreeMarkerContent

fun main(args: Array<String>) {    
    embeddedServer(Netty, 3000) {    
        install(FreeMarker) {
            templateLoader = ClassTemplateLoader(TheApp::class.java.classLoader, "templates")
        }

        routing {
            get("/") {
                call.respond(FreeMarkerContent("templ.ftl", "", "e"))
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true) }
```

gradle portion:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.21'
}

group 'rest-group'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

ext.ktor_version = '1.1.3'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile "io.ktor:ktor:$ktor_version"
    compile "io.ktor:ktor-gson:$ktor_version"
    compile "io.ktor:ktor-freemarker:$ktor_version"
    compile "io.ktor:ktor-html-builder:$ktor_version"
    compile "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version"
    compile "io.ktor:ktor-auth:$ktor_version"
    compile "io.ktor:ktor:$ktor_version"
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'TheApp' needs to be replaced with 'this'. 'this' picks up the instance of the application being run for ktor.

'model' needs to be a mapOf reference type even if the values aren't being used.